# Are there any alternatives for a cathode ray oscilloscope

Tags: oscilloscope

I am conducting a few basic electronic experiments at my home. To measure the variables of these experiments, I need to analyze their input and output wave forms. This would require a cathode ray oscilloscope. So, I would like to know if there are any alternative method I can do.

Also I have been wondering whether there is any means by which I can connect my electronic circuits to my computer and analyze the wave forms using any appropriate software that would work like a CRO?

Comment: Welcome to the 21st century, and the digital oscilloscopes world!

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=digital+oscilloscope&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiUqcOtn__LAhXE7hoKHYmbCCkQ_AUICCgC&biw=1293&bih=902

Comment: There are also lots of affordable "soft" oscopes out there that are good enough for hobbyists. Google is your friend.

Comment: Note that the suggestions to use a PC with soundcard as an oscilloscope won't do you much good if you are working with DC signals.  What kind of experiments are you doing?

Comment: I wonder if this is a language issue and he really means "oscilloscope" instead of it being explicitly cathode ray-based.

Comment: Why would you even start with a CRO and then consider the others alternatives?  A CRO can be a alternative to common scopes for specialized uses, but starting with that in mind is backwards.

Comment: Please ask as a NEW QUESTION.  Your edit borders on vandalism.  I rolled it back

Comment: i cant ask a new question. i have been banned for 3 months. i need help.

Comment: If you have been banned, it is for low quality posts and/or unacceptable behaviour. Performing more behaviour that's even more unacceptable is ___NOT___ going to make that any better. Rather than spending time trying to break the rules every which way, spend time learning to interact in a smarter way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on the bandwidth of the signals. For slow varying signals, your sound card can behave as a low cost oscilloscope.
http://homediyelectronics.com/projects/howtomakeafreesoundcardpcoscilloscope/

Comment: But not at DC..

Answer (score 5):

> Are there any alternatives for a cathode ray oscilloscope

**Obviously**, as even a minute looking at what's available would have revealed.  In fact, cathode ray oscilloscopes (CROs) are now harder to find than digital oscilloscopes.

Even new entry level scopes are all digital.  They are smaller, cheaper, and more flexible than CROs.  Today, CROs are mostly found in museums and when people sell off old stuff.  I gave my last CRO away to a high school student a few years ago since I hadn't used it in the previous 10 years.  It was a decent enough Tektronix model in its day, but the trigger was a little flaky, and it just didn't have enough value to make it worth doing anything else with.

Answer (score 3):

CROs can still be useful if you are doing extremely fast circuits- such as those scopes with microchannel plates- but for most hobby applications an inexpensive LCD digital oscilloscopes will do just fine.

They all have their limitations (X-Y mode is miserable in many cheap digital scopes, and aliasing can be a bugger if you're not expecting it).

At the really low end there are some Chinese single board scopes that tie together an LCD display and an ARM processor to make a dubious low frequency scope. I would suggest saving the coin ($300-400) for an entry level Rigol or similar scope if you are serious- it will make all the difference.

Without a scope you are working blind- a decent oscilloscope opens up the mysteries of your circuits and lets you see (albeit through a glass, darkly) what is really going on. Your strange and drifting DC levels may actually be MHz oscillation, to give just one example.

Answer (score 2):

Despite the fact that I still use one, CRO is utterly obsolete - then again, perhaps that's why I own one ;-) - I can afford to.

Virtually all modern scopes are digital storage with a flat display screen. If your needs are very low frequency, some programs do exist that will use a sound card as an oscilloscope and waveform generator. Otherwise there are a few external scope-head units that will use something else (computer, phone, tablet) as the display out there.

Comment: can you please name those programs?

Comment: Shopping is a no no... but I know Daqarta as one. http://www.daqarta.com/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

You could use a laser pointer, a polygonal mirror to do the horizontal scanning (similar to the ones used in barcode scanners), and a flat plane mirror controlled by a piezo actuator to do the vertical reflections. This laser dot could be projected on any wall.

The signal would be amplified and fed to the piezo actuator. It would not consume much power. Piezo actuators can be moved very fast and with incredible precision. It would be a true solid-state analog oscilloscope.